# Can't add component to panel in scrollPane in java

Tags: java, user-interface, panel, jscrollpane

I'm working in desktop application in Java. I put a scroll pane and put a panel inside it to add a Label called `name` and an empty TextField and a button called `more`. What I want is when the button is clicked, a new Label and a TextField shall appear under the first Label and TextField, but nothing appears. Here is my code for the button:

```
private void moreActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name :");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    i++;
    nameLabel.setBounds(
      child_namelabel.getX(), child_namelabel.getY() + 35 * i,
      child_namelabel.getWidth(), child_namelabel.getHeight());
    panel.add(nameLabel);
    children.add(panel);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From Java-Api:

```
This method changes layout-related information, and therefore, invalidates the component hierarchy.
If the container has already been displayed, the hierarchy must be validated thereafter in order to
display the added component.
```

So you call:

```
children.validate();
```

at the end of your method.